# BNF to handle escape sequence

Tags: parsing, escaping, grammar, bnf

I use this BNF to parser my script:

```
{identset} = {ASCII} - {"\{\}};     //<--all ascii charset except '\"' '{' and '}'
{strset}   = {ASCII} - {"};
ident      = {identset}*;
str        = {strset}*;
node     ::= ident "{" nodes "}" |  //<--entry point
             "\"" str "\"" | 
             ident;
nodes    ::= node nodes |
             node;
```

It can parse correctly the following text into tree structure

```
doc {
    title { "some title goes here" }
    refcode { "SDS-1" }
    rev { "1.0" }
    revdate { "04062010" }
    body {  
        "this is the body of the document
         all text should go here"
        chapter { "some inline section" }
        "text again"
    }
}
```

my question is, **how do I handle escape sequence inside string** literal:

```
"some text of \"quotation\" should escape"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define str as:

```
str =  ( strset strescape ) *;
```

with

```
strescape = { \\ } {\" } ;
```